# Why doesn't supervisor log the output of a child process?

Tags: logs, supervisord

When I run the script `server.sh` (runs a quake dedicated server) in the terminal it will create initialization output like

```
------- Game Initialization -------
gamename: baseqz
gamedate: May 25 2016
initializing access list...
loaded 0 steam ids into the access list
Not logging to disk.
0 teams with 0 entities
21 items registered
```

And when some person connects to the server then this script will output something like `Person xyz has connected`

I want supervisor to manage this *server.sh* script but supervisor does not output any kind of initialization messages or connecting message (if someone connects).
Stdout and stderr are both logged. Why does supervisor not log the output of *server.sh*?

Here is my **supervisord.conf**

```
[program:prog]
command=/home/user/.steam/steamapps/common/qlds/server.sh
stdout_logfile=stdout.txt
stderr_logfile=stdout.txt

[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=http://127.0.0.1:9001

[inet_http_server]
port=127.0.0.1:9001

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface
```

EDIT:
I noticed a strange behaviour of server.sh

```
server.sh &> out.txt
```

generates no output in out.txt (no Game initialization, nothink). But only after i typed in stdin "quit" (server.sh quits now) then the Game initialization and so on got written into file out.txt

Answer (score 0):

try full path for std logfiles and ensure permissions are set correctly.

```
stdout_logfile=/abc/stdout.txt
stderr_logfile=/abc/stdout.txt
```